# How to install Access database engine on Microsoft Server 2012 R2

Tags: ms-office

I need to install Microsoft Access database engine Redistributable on Microsoft Server 2012 R2. But i'm unable to install coz the supported operating system does not have Microsoft Server 2012 R2. Is there any other way to install or re-solve this!!

Answer (score 0):

I thought Access ran on the server license.  Not sure on this.  You might just put a quick small Access file onto it and see if it will open and run.